# Symfony 4.2 Form ChoiceType Expanded Multiple can not populate check boxes from database and save changes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, select, symfony4

### Introduction

For my personal project i am using

- `Symfony v4.2.1`
- `PHP v7.2.12`
- `Windows 10`

I have tree structure that represents directories and files. I have to restrict access to items in folder file tree. For that purpose there is an entity that has `id`, `access levels` (look at the 1st code block for an example) and references to `user` and `file tree`.

In order to manage this i am using `AccessSetupType` (see 2nd code block that represents my form).

### Problem explanation

At the moment form is displayed. Select option elements are shown and corresponding option values from 0 to 4 are set up.

After post i seem to get only changed fields (correct count, but always with value false) not all the check boxes with their respective values!

### Questions

1. How to pass choices (as in 1st example) to the form and automatically fill in check boxes with data from database?
2. How to pass all elements not only checked to controller when submitting form?

### Code

> 1st code block ($access_info)

```
$access_info = [
  "can_see" => true
  "can_download" => false
  "can_upload" => false
  "can_delete" => true
  "is_owner" => false
]
```

> 2nd code block (AccessSetupType)

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AccessSetupType extends AbstractType
{
    private $access_choices;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->access_choices = $options['access_choices'];

        $builder
            ->add('accessSetup', ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Access level:',
                    'choices' => $this->access_choices,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'checkbox-custom'],
                    'translation_domain' => 'form_access',
                    'empty_data' => false
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'access_choices' => null,
                'data_class' => null,
                'csrf_protection' => true,
                'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

> 3rd code block (relevant part of controller)

```
$file_tree_node_id = 17;
$user_id = 5;

$access_choices = $repo_file_tree_access->getFileTreeAccessByNodeAndUser($node_id, $user_id);

$form = $this->createForm(AccessSetupType::class, null, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_access_setup_with_node_id', ['node_id' => $node_id]),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'node_id' => $node_id,
    'access_choices' => $access_choices,
));

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
{
    $data = $form['accessSetup']->getData();
    dump($data);

    if ($form->get('saveAccess')->isClicked())
    {
        // save clicked
        dump('save clicked');

        $file_tree_access = new FileTreeAccess();
        $file_tree_access->setCanSee($data[0]);
        $file_tree_access->setCanDownload($data[1]);
        $file_tree_access->setCanUpload($data[2]);
        $file_tree_access->setCanDelete($data[3]);
        $file_tree_access->setIsOwner($data[4]);
        $file_tree_access->setUser($repo_user->findOneBy(['id' => $user_id]));
        $file_tree_access->setFileTree($repo_file_tree->getOneFileTreeNode($file_tree_node_id));

        if (($file_tree_access !== null) && ($file_tree_access !== []))
        {
            //$em->persist($file_tree_access);
            //$em->flush();
        }
    }
    else if ($form->get('return')->isClicked())
    {
        // return clicked
        dump('return clicked');
    }
}
```

> 4th code block (FileTreeAccess instance example)

```
array:8 [
    "id" => 4
    "can_see" => true
    "can_download" => false
    "can_upload" => false
    "can_delete" => false
    "is_owner" => false
    "file_tree_id" => 16
    "user_id" => 5
]
```

### Rendered Form

This is how form is rendered after i clicked on options.

It does not display selected choices form database.

[image]

### Conclusion

What am i doing wrong? What am i missing?

Thank you for ideas!

### Update 1

I am already passing FileTreeAccess record (see 4th code block) to the form.

If i pass to the form constructor second argument `new FileTreeAccess()`

I have following error:

- `Cannot read index "accessSetup" from object of type "App\Entity\FileTreeAccess" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.`

### Update 2

> I think the problem source might be - that in order to manage access to `FileTree` i need to pass to the form only 5 of 8 entity properties (those that represent permissions). How to do that? Maybe i need the DataTransformer for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your options pre-filled, you have to tie your form to an object. Then when you submit the form, you won't need to set everything, it is done automatically.

```
$file_tree_access = new FileTreeAccess();

// load data from database here then set them in your object before passing it to the form

$form = $this->createForm(AccessSetupType::class, $file_tree_access, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_access_setup_with_node_id', ['node_id' => $node_id]),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'node_id' => $node_id,
    'access_choices' => $access_choices,
));

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: Hello, @hoover_D!
I tried your proposition, but in this case i get an error. `Cannot read index "accessSetup" from object of type "App\Entity\FileTreeAccess" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.`